# How can I remove all blank spaces per line from either Excel and/or Notepad++, without merging all lines into one single line?

Tags: excel, notepad++

First post here on stackoverflow, tried to search across the web but couldn't find the solution. If the question has already been answered, sorry!

I'm trying to do the following in either or both Excel and Notepad++:

**Text Example:**

```
1 2 3
1  2  3
1   2   3
```

**Desired Output:**

```
123
123
123
```

I've looked at several solutions and the below example is ***not*** what I am looking for:

```
123123123
```

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HLDw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, just found the solution for Notepad++!

Find what: [ \t]+
Replace with:

Hopefully this can help anyone moving forward.  If those post has already been answered elsewhere, please go ahead and delete this.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `[ \t]+` you can use `\h+` (horizontal spaces)